# Server side language for cpu/memory intensive process

Tags: programming-languages

Whats a good server side language for doing some pretty cpu and memory intensive things that plays well with php and mysql. Currently, I have a php script which runs some calculations based on a large subset of a fairly large database and than updates that database based on those calculations (1.5millions rows). The current implementation is very slow, taking 1-2 hours depending on other activities on the server. I was hoping to improve this and was wondering what peoples opinions are on a good language for this type of task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language isn't the issue, your issue is probably *where* you are doing these calculations. Sounds like you may be better off writing this in SQL, if possible. Is it? What are you doing?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible. Do you think that would produce the best results?

Comment: Most definitely. It'll mean that it's executing right on your server, and the data won't need to be transferred over to PHP/Whatever first.

Answer (score 3):

Where is the bottleneck? Run some real profiling, and see what exactly is causing the problem. Is it the DB I/O? Is it the cpu? Is the algorithm inefficient? Are you calling slow library methods in a tight inner loop? Could precalculation be used.

You're pretty much asking what vehicle you need to get from point A to point B, and you've offered a truck, car, bicycle, airplane, jet, and helicopter. The answer won't make sense without more context.

Comment: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7213

May or may not be useful. This looks like the cprofile module for python, which I found quite handy.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your bottleneck is not the computation. It definitely takes several hours to just update a few million records.

If that's the case, you can write a customized function in c/c++ for MySQL and execute the function in stored procedure.

We do this in our database to re-encrypt some sensitive fields during key-rotation. It shrunk key-rotation time from days to hours. However, it's a pain to maintain your own copy of MySQL.  We have been looking for alternatives but nothing is close to the performance of this approach.